# Postdoc interview result

Tags: postdocs

I have given an interview for a Postdoc position at UCSF, USA by an Assistant Professor recruiting his 1st postdoc. I was interviewed three times (1st over phone, followed by two skype interviews).

In the last interview the PI described about his on-going and future projects and he went on to say "when you come here to my lab..." Which I believe was a slip of tongue.

At the end of the discussion, he told that I will mail you the decision letter in a couple of days. It's been a week since that happened but I have not got any reply yet. Does it mean my application is rejected or its too early to think so? When should I get in touch with him.

Comment: We know no more than you do. I'd give it another week, then ask about the progress of your application via email. Good luck!

Comment: @ Emma Thank you for replying, i agree with you but... its very difficult to wait in such case.

Comment: I know it's difficult, having been there myself. The only thing you can do is have patience.

Answer (score 4):

> Does it mean my application is rejected

No, it doesn't.

It just means that for whatever reason, the decision or informing you of the decision is delayed.

> or its too early to think so? When should i get in touch with him.

You could get in touch now, or wait another week or so.

Before I started a postdoc in Canada I had the same situation and I asked (I think the PI had promised to let me know informally in two days, but then I still heard nothing after a week) .  The PI then quickly replied that she had to clarify some issues with the funding agency before she could inform the successful candidate.  Several more days later I had a postdoc offer, and one year longer than originally advertised.